# Disable the WATCH command on ZNC

Tags: irc

On ZNC, there's a `WATCH` command (not the `watch` module) that is used as a server-side watchlist. It automatically adds people I've PM'd and notifies me when they come on/offline which gets quite annoying. I know I can do `WATCH -nick` to remove a nick, but I don't want to do that all the time to remove every nick it automatically adds. Is there any way to disable this `WATCH` command all together?

**EDIT**: The only actual access to ZNC I have is through the web administration interface. And I'm not an administrator, only a regular user, on the server.

Comment: Honestly, I'd ask at #znc on EFNet.  That's where the dev team lives.  You'll get the most help there.

Comment: I've been looking at http://en.znc.in/wiki/Watch and don't interpret it as defaulting to the behavior you have described above. Is it non-standard or have you previously changed any settings? What's in `/msg *watch list` or `/msg *watch dump` for example

Comment: @PriceChild: Whenever I try either of those, it says `No such module [watch]`.

Answer (score 2):

As ZNC is open-source, I downloaded and analyzed it.

For your information, the WATCH command is handled (surprise) by the Watch module, in the source file `modules\watch.cpp`. At line 240 of the file, you will find the following :

```
virtual void OnModCommand(const CString& sCommand) {
    CString sCmdName = sCommand.Token(0);
    if (sCmdName.Equals("ADD") || sCmdName.Equals("WATCH")) {
        Watch(sCommand.Token(1), sCommand.Token(2), sCommand.Token(3, true));
```

To nullify the WATCH command, you can either :

1. Unload the Watch module, which supposedly makes the WATCH command inaccessible
2. Change the string "WATCH" in the source to something else and re-compile
3. Use a [free hex editor](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-hex-editor.htm) to search the binary for the string "WATCH" (without the quotes) and change it, while keeping the same total number of characters, for example to "VATCH".

As I don't use ZNC, I cannot measure the impact of unloading the Watch module on its normal functioning. The other two solutions will need to be repeated for each new release of ZNC.

Comment: @Mark Szymanski: As your downvote and criticism of my previous answer was unjustified and incited others to do the same, I expect at least an apology.

Comment: The watch module is already unloaded, so it's odd that the WATCH command is still working. Also, I am not going to apologize. Your answer was wrong, and I downvoted. That's how the system works. Get over it.

Comment: My answer was not wrong : It is probable that the Watch module is auto-loaded upon reference, which is the basis of your misconception that command and module are totally distinct.

Comment: I apologize for not illustrating this point before, but unfortunately I don't have access enough to the server to do the second or third solutions. And the first solution doesn't work.

Comment: The problem is apparently that unloading the Watch module has really no effect, as it is reloaded on demand. One could try to delete its module `watch.dll`, but this could cause problems. Although if you have good enough access to do that, you should also be capable of modifying it as per solutions 2 and 3 or similar.

Comment: @harrymc: If this watch module *is* loaded, it isn't showing up as loaded when I list the modules (either via the web interface or from `*status`). Also, I will repeat what I said, the second and third solutions will *not* work. I don't have shell access to the server.

Comment: The ZNC management of modules is apparently a bit special, so the 1st solution has no effect. The other solutions are apparently the only way that this will work, but as you cannot modify ZNC then you also cannot delete a command. I wouldn't have tried answering this post if your edit was there when I started.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the other answer/comments I get the idea that doing this server side isn't going to happen [easily]...

So... what about client side?

It is obviously dependent on your client, but can you ignore them from there?

Comment: I'll see if I could ignore it, I'll try when I get the chance. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I cannot ignore it with my client (irssi). Thanks for the answer though!